# how to print total in footer in table using codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter framework. how to get total in purchase order column in footer.

```
$return_array[] = array(
    'brand_name'=>$row->brand_name,
    'product_type'=>$row->product_type,
    'product_flavour'=>$row->product_flavour,
    'dealer_price'=>$dealer_price,
    'price'=>$price ,
    'openStock'=>$openStock,
    'total_purchase'=>$toatal_purchase,
    'free_issuese_in'=>$free_issuese_in,   
    'stock_tra_in'=>$stock_tra_in,
    'tot'=> number_format(count($openStock) > 0 ? $openStock[0]->openStock:0,2)+($toatal_purchase[0]->totalPurchase)+($free_issuese_in[0]->freeIssueseIn)+($stock_tra_in[0]->stocktrain),//total
    'totalsales'=>$totalSales,
    'stockTraOut'=>$stockTraOut,
    'freeIssuesOut'=>$freeIssuesOut,
    'clossing_blnc'=>  number_format(count($stockTraOut)> 0 ? $stockTraOut[0]->stockTraOut :0,2)+( $freeIssuesOut[0]->freeIssuesOut)+($totalSales[0]->totalsales)-(number_format(count($openStock) > 0 ? $openStock[0]->openStock:0,2)+($toatal_purchase[0]->totalPurchase)+($free_issuese_in[0]->freeIssueseIn)+($stock_tra_in[0]->stocktrain))//closing balance
);
```

those data i pass to body...... here 7 column is the total purchase column. that column data i want to get sum for footer another id . i pass those data using  json parse.

```
for( var x=0; x<order.length;x++) {
    order_detail.push(
        '<tr>'
         +'<td>'+ order[x].brand_name + '</td>'
         +'<td>'+ order[x].product_type + '</td>'
         +'<td>'+ order[x].product_flavour +'</td>'
         +'<td id="mm">' + order[x].dealer_price[0].dealer_price +'</td>'
         +'<td id="yy"  style="display:none;">' + order[x].price[0].price+'</td>'
         +'<td>' + order[x].openStock[0].openStock +'</td>'
         +'<td>' + order[x].total_purchase[0].totalPurchase+'</td>'
         +'<td>'+ order[x].free_issuese_in[0].freeIssueseIn + '</td>'
         +'<td>'+ order[x].stock_tra_in[0].stocktrain + '</td>'
         +'<td>' + order[x].tot+'</td>'
         +'<td>' + order[x].totalsales[0].totalsales+'</td>' 
         +'<td>'+ order[x].stockTraOut[0].stockTraOut + '</td>'
         +'<td>'+ order[x].freeIssuesOut[0].freeIssuesOut + '</td>'
         +'<td>'+ order[x].clossing_blnc + '</td>'
         +'</tr>'
   );

}
sweetAlert("Good job!", "monthly stock Succsessfully filter !", "success");
//  $j('#lbl_rescount').text('0');
//  $j('#sl_amount').text(order['totals_td'][0].tot_purchase);

// $j('#sl_amount').html(tot1);
$j('#order_body').html(order_detail);
```

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: i want to get total in purchase order column.....in table footer... how to code it.... in model file inside array function i can not calcutate sum  of total purchase ....

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your Original Post is confusing. You start by showing PHP, then JS, leaving us to assume many things.

My assumption is that you are first creating the `$return_array` in your controller, then passing this to your view. Then in your view, you are somehow passing this to JS. Are you using AJAX? Are you just passing this information straight to a PHP view?

If you are using AJAX, and then using `JSON.parse()` to convert `$return_array[]` to `order` then why not just do the following?

```
var total = 0;
for( var x=0; x<order.length;x++) {
    total+= order[x].total_purchase[0].totalPurchase;
    order_detail.push(
        //your table code
   );

}
$("footer").html(total);
```